# Getting error when trying to post to mysql “Cannot read property 'create' of undefined”

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am working with node, sequelize, migration and mysql. I have already done the sequelize init and defined my models in the file of 'models'. I am testing my first endpoint in the server.js file but when I want run the post this message appears:

> Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

I have read a lot of issues and it is supposed that with the next require I can access my model.

**Students.js(model)**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

  const students = sequelize.define('students', {

    dep_id:{
      type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull:false,
    },
    name:{
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull:false,
    },
    surname:{
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull:false,
    },
    number:{
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      unique:true,
      allowNull:false,
    },
    phone:{
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      unique:true,
      allowNull:false,
    },
    mail:{
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      unique:true,
      allowNull:false,
    } ,
    password:{
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull:false,
    },
    actives:{
      type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull:false,
    },
    confirm_key:{
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull:false,
    },
  
 }, {tableName:"students"
});


    students.associate =(models) =>{
      // define association here
    
  };

  return students;
};
```

**AuthController.js(controller)**

```
const {Students} = require('../models/index');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const authConfig= require('../../config/auth');
module.exports={
    signIn(req,res)
    {

    },
    signUp(req,res){
        Students.create(req.body);
    }

}
```

**routes.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const AuthController=require('./controllers/AuthController');

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.json({ message:'hello'});
});

router.post('/api/signin',AuthController.signIn)
router.post('/api/signup',AuthController.signUp)


module.exports=router;
```

**index.js(model)**

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);

const config = require('../../config/database');

const db = {};

let sequelize  = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);


fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
```

return is the students. Problem is in model name error